# regular expression - German participles

Tags: javascript, expression

I'd need a hand for regular expressions concerning German past participles: most of them start with "ge" and end either on "en" or "t", unless they are declinated, in which case there are either one or two additional characters. Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Can you give an example of each type of input that can match (i.e. one that ends with `en`, `t`, and a *declinated?* string)?

Comment: I know plenty of reg-ex to help you but not nearly enough German, perhapes you could be a little more specific about what you want to match.

Comment: Examples:

most participles look like this:

gakauft, gemacht, gesagt, gearbeitet, gelesen, gegangen, gesungen, geschwommen

when they're declinated a one or 2-digit ending is appended:

gelesene, gekaufte, gezeigten, geschriebenem

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex will capture the undeclinated verbs starting with *ge-* and ending with *-t* or *-en* and the declinations ending with *-te*, *-ene*, *-tem*, and *-enem*

```
^ge[a-z]+(t|en)(e*)(m*)$
```

[Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/fADO2XPWDn)